# SignalR thinks request is cross domain

Tags: iis, signalr, load-balancing, signalr-hub, f5

We faced an issue in our staging environment where SignalR thought the request was coming from another domain. So, we enabled CORS for the time being...however, we realized that we were downgraded to long polling which means we can't maintain server affinity.

We are using .NET 4 / SignalR 1.2.2 and our request goes through an F5 load balancer. We're trying to debug this issue, obtain logs and disable CORS to get exact details. I tried to map a hub with "http://domainname.com/signalr", but it didn't work. The application lanuched without complaining, but I couldn't connect to signalr anymore. Since we're on .NET 4, we can't move to using the latest version / WebSockets.

What is the best way to instruct SignalR to allow a range of domains? (I've also tried multiple calls to map hubs, but that failed).

**UPDATE:**

Upon further investigation, I've realized that that the application can be accessed internally and externally. SignalR seems to bind to the machine name. Hence, everything works on the local url. However, when we make a request from an external domain which the F5 load balancer forwards, SignalR thinks it's a cross-site request....which theoretically it isn't in this case.

Is it possible that this is a F5 issue?

Is there a way to ask SignalR to allow certain domains without downgrading to longPolling?

Comment: Use fiddler, and verify SignalR's request response, and verify what's the exact error.

Comment: Have you implemented ScaleOut in SignalR ?

Comment: If you're referring to Redis, etc., then no we haven't. Our application doesn't require server affinity except for a particular use-case for which we're using SignalR. I'll check the exact logs after another deployment where we'll turn off CORS. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you've implemented load balancing then you must implement scale out in SignalR

take a look at [ScaleOut in SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-in-signalr)
One approach is ScaleOut with SQL Server : [Have a look](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-with-sql-server)

Comment: What does my problem have to do with ScaleOut? The receiving server thinks the request is originating from a different domain...it's not. How is this answering my question?